# Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to do something like this :

```
myYear = record.GetValueOrNull<int?>("myYear"),
```

Notice the nullable type as the generic parameter.

Since the `GetValueOrNull` function could return null my first attempt was this:

```
public static T GetValueOrNull<T>(this DbDataRecord reader, string columnName)
  where T : class
{
    object columnValue = reader[columnName];

    if (!(columnValue is DBNull))
    {
        return (T)columnValue;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the error I'm getting now is:

> The type 'int?' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Right! `Nullable<int>` is a `struct`! So I tried changing the class constraint to a `struct` constraint (and as a side effect can't return `null` any more):

```
public static T GetValueOrNull<T>(this DbDataRecord reader, string columnName)
  where T : struct
```

Now the assignment:

```
myYear = record.GetValueOrNull<int?>("myYear");
```

Gives the following error:

> The type 'int?' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Is specifying a nullable type as a generic parameter at all possible?

Comment: Pls pls make your signature `IDataRecord` from `DbDataRecord`..

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Change the return type to `Nullable<T>`, and call the method with the non nullable parameter

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? i = GetValueOrNull<int>(null, string.Empty);
}


public static Nullable<T> GetValueOrNull<T>(DbDataRecord reader, string columnName) where T : struct
{
    object columnValue = reader[columnName];

    if (!(columnValue is DBNull))
        return (T)columnValue;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use "columnValue == DBNull.Value" instead of the 'is' operator, because its slightly faster =)

Comment: Personal preference, but you can use the short form T? instead of Nullable<T>

Comment: This is fine for value types, but then I think it won't work at all with reference types (e.g. GetValueOrNull<string>) because C# doesn't seem to like Nullable<(ref type)> like "string?". Robert C Barth & James Jones's solutions, below, seem much better to me if that's your need.

Comment: @bacar - right, hence the "where T : struct", if you want reference types you can create a similar method with "where T: class"

Comment: @Greg - sure, but then you need a second method, and you can't overload the name. As I say, *if* you want to handle both val and ref types, I think  cleaner solutions are presented on this page.

Comment: @bacar There's a good reason for that - nullable allows "sort-of-null", but it still has value semantics, not reference semantics. `Nullable\`1` is a special type as far as the runtime is concerned, and a lot of "magic" is involved.

Comment: Not specifically requested in the question, but this is the best option if you want your method to take a `T` parameter but need to return the nullable form `T?`. It does have the limitations @bacar mentions though.

Comment: With .NET 5 I get the compiler error `CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'T?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. What's wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: What if i want to cover such types: `long`, `int`, `string`? String is not a struct. How to make generic with nullable parameter nevertheless?

Answer (score 127):

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this IDataRecord rdr, int index)
{
    object val = rdr[index];

    if (!(val is DBNull))
        return (T)val;

    return default(T);
}
```

Just use it like this:

```
decimal? Quantity = rdr.GetValueOrDefault<decimal?>(1);
string Unit = rdr.GetValueOrDefault<string>(2);
```

Comment: This could be shortened to: return rdr.IsDBNull(index) ? default(T) : (T)rdr[index];

Comment: I think this question explicitly wants _null_, not _default(T)_.

Comment: @mafu default(T) will return null for reference types, and 0 for numerical types, making the solution more flexible.

Comment: I think it's clearer to either call this `GetValueOrDefault` to clarify that it returns `default(T)` rather than `null`. Alternatively, you could have it throw an exception if `T` is not nullable.

Comment: This method has a lot of advantages, and forces you to think about returning something other than null as well.

Comment: @mafu for value types you can explicitly tell that you are looking for nulls: GetValueOrDefault<decimal?>

Answer (score 69):

Just do two things to your original code – remove the `where` constraint, and change the last `return` from `return null` to `return default(T)`. This way you can return whatever type you want.

By the way, you can avoid the use of `is` by changing your `if` statement to `if (columnValue != DBNull.Value)`.

Comment: This solution does not work, as there is a logical difference between NULL and 0

Comment: It works if the type he passes is int?. It will return NULL, just like he wants. If he passes int as the type, it will return 0 since an int can't be NULL. Besides the fact that I tried it and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is the most correct and flexible answer. However, `return default` is sufficient (you don't need the `(T)`, the compiler will infer it from the signature return type).

Answer (score 8):

Multiple generic constraints can't be combined in an OR fashion (less restrictive), only in an AND fashion (more restrictive). Meaning that one method can't handle both scenarios. The generic constraints also cannot be used to make a unique signature for the method, so you'd have to use 2 separate method names.

However, you can use the generic constraints to make sure that the methods are used correctly.

In my case, I specifically wanted null to be returned, and never the default value of any possible value types. GetValueOrDefault = bad. GetValueOrNull = good.

I used the words "Null" and "Nullable" to distinguish between reference types and value types. And here is an example of a couple extension methods I wrote that compliments the FirstOrDefault method in System.Linq.Enumerable class.

```
    public static TSource FirstOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TSource: class
    {
        if (source == null) return null;
        var result = source.FirstOrDefault();   // Default for a class is null
        return result;
    }

    public static TSource? FirstOrNullable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource?> source)
        where TSource : struct
    {
        if (source == null) return null;
        var result = source.FirstOrDefault();   // Default for a nullable is null
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you want unified overloaded calls - just use the same names in the signatures: `TSource FirstOrNull<TSource>(TSource? source) where TSource : class` and `TSource FirstOrNull<TSource>(TSource? source) where TSource : struct`

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** This answer works, but is intended for educational purposes only. :) [James Jones' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517264/70345) is probably the best here and certainly the one I'd go with.

C# 4.0's `dynamic` keyword makes this even easier, if less safe:

```
public static dynamic GetNullableValue(this IDataRecord record, string columnName)
{
  var val = reader[columnName];

  return (val == DBNull.Value ? null : val);
}
```

Now you don't need the explicit type hinting on the RHS:

```
int? value = myDataReader.GetNullableValue("MyColumnName");
```

In fact, you don't need it anywhere!

```
var value = myDataReader.GetNullableValue("MyColumnName");
```

`value` will now be an int, or a string, or whatever type was returned from the DB.

The only problem is that this does not prevent you from using non-nullable types on the LHS, in which case you'll get a rather nasty runtime exception like:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
```

As with all code that uses `dynamic`: caveat coder.

Comment: I'd avoid dynamic types in this case as they are not necessary.  Dynamic types have a significant performance overhead.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to handle Reference types and struct types.
I use it to convert XML Element strings to a more typed type.
You can remove the nullAlternative with reflection.
The formatprovider is to handle the culture dependent '.' or ',' separator in e.g. decimals or ints and doubles.
This may work:

```
public T GetValueOrNull<T>(string strElementNameToSearchFor, IFormatProvider provider = null ) 
    {
        IFormatProvider theProvider = provider == null ? Provider : provider;
        XElement elm = GetUniqueXElement(strElementNameToSearchFor);

        if (elm == null)
        {
            object o =  Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            return (T)o; 
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Type type = typeof(T);
                if (type.IsGenericType &&
                type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                {
                    type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
                }
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(elm.Value, type, theProvider); 
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                return (T)o; 
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
iRes = helper.GetValueOrNull<int?>("top_overrun_length");
Assert.AreEqual(100, iRes);



decimal? dRes = helper.GetValueOrNull<decimal?>("top_overrun_bend_degrees");
Assert.AreEqual(new Decimal(10.1), dRes);

String strRes = helper.GetValueOrNull<String>("top_overrun_bend_degrees");
Assert.AreEqual("10.1", strRes);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just had to do something incredible similar to this. My code:

```
public T IsNull<T>(this object value, T nullAlterative)
{
    if(value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type.IsGenericType && 
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())
        {
            type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        }

        return (T)(type.IsEnum ? Enum.ToObject(type, Convert.ToInt32(value)) :
            Convert.ChangeType(value, type));
    }
    else 
        return nullAlternative;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The shorter way :

```
public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow reader, string columnName) => 
        reader.IsNull(columnName) ? default : (T) reader[columnName];
```

return `0` for `int`, and `null` for `int?`

Answer (score 4):

Incase it helps someone - I have used this before and seems to do what I need it to...

```
public static bool HasValueAndIsNotDefault<T>(this T? v)
    where T : struct
{
    return v.HasValue && !v.Value.Equals(default(T));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be a dead thread, but I tend to use the following:

```
public static T? GetValueOrNull<T>(this DbDataRecord reader, string columnName)
where T : struct 
{
    return reader[columnName] as T?;
}
```

Comment: "The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'"

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here is another solution:

```
public static bool GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlDataReader Reader, string ColumnName, out T Result)
{
    try
    {
        object ColumnValue = Reader[ColumnName];

        Result = (ColumnValue!=null && ColumnValue != DBNull.Value) ? (T)ColumnValue : default(T);

        return ColumnValue!=null && ColumnValue != DBNull.Value;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Possibly an invalid cast?
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, you don't care if `T` was value or reference type. Only if the function returns true, you have a reasonable value from the database.
Usage:

```
...
decimal Quantity;
if (rdr.GetValueOrDefault<decimal>("YourColumnName", out Quantity))
{
    // Do something with Quantity
}
```

This approach is very similar to `int.TryParse("123", out MyInt);`

Comment: It would be good if you worked on your naming conventions. They lack consistency. In one place there is a variable without a capital then there is one with. The same with parameters to the methods.

Comment: Done and done! Hope code looks better now. Bob's your auntie :) All is skookum

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem myself.

`... = reader["myYear"] as int?;` works and is clean.

It works with any type without an issue. If the result is DBNull, it returns null as the conversion fails.

Comment: In fact, you could probably do `int v=reader["myYear"]??-1;` or some other default instead of `-1`. However, this might bring up issues if the value is `DBNull`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method I've used for years:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this DbDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnName))
        throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(columnName));

    // do not swallow exceptions here - let them bubble up to the calling API to be handled and/or logged
    var index = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(index))
    {
        return (T)reader.GetValue(index);
    }
    return default;
}
```