# Can I create a generic function that accepts a Nullable<something>?

Tags: .net, generics, nullable

I'm working on a method that will accept a StreamWriter, either a string or a nullable value, and a length, and write the value to the StreamWriter, padded to the length. If the value is null, I want to write spaces. I want to do something like the following oversimplified example, which is just for demonstration purposes.

```
public void FixedWrite(StreamWriter writer, string value, 
        int length) {
    if (value == null) value = "";
    value = value.PadRight(length);
    writer.Write(value);
}

public void FixedWrite<T>(StreamWriter writer, T value, 
        int length) where T : Nullable /* won't work of course */ {
    string strVal;
    if (!value.HasValue) strVal = null;
    else strVal = value.Value.ToString();
    FixedWrite(writer, strVal, length);
}
```

I could have overloads for all the different underlying types (they're all dates, ints, bools and decimals), but I wanted to see if I could get the generic version working. Is there some way of getting T to always be a Nullable<> type, and to access the Nullable<> properties (HasValue and Value)? Or should I just stick with the underlying-type-specific overloads?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible) poses a similar problem, but in my case the values are already nullables and I just want to write out the value if it has one and spaces if it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void FixedWrite<T>(StreamWriter writer, Nullable<T> value, int length) 
    where T : struct
{
    string strVal;
    if (!value.HasValue) strVal = null;
    else strVal = value.HasValue.ToString();
    FixedWrite(writer, strVal, length);
}
```

Comment: Of course. I was making it harder than it needed to be. Thanks.

Comment: This works, but you *can* still pass a nullable parameter to the generic method.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void FixedWrite<T>(StreamWriter writer, Nullable<T> value, int length)
```

Anything wrong with that?

Comment: In order for this to compile you must constrain `T` as a value type, please see my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was too lazy to fire up VS to find out what the compiler actually says :).

Answer (score 1):

No need to test for HasValue, since Nullable is a struct, you can impose the "new()" constraint:

```
public void FixedWrite<T>(StreamWriter writer, T value, int length) where T : new()
{
    // just test for NULL
    string strVal = (value==null) ? string.Empty: value.ToString();
    FixedWrite(writer, strVal, length);
}
```

Now you call it like so (using the "?" notation is the key):

```
FixedValue<System.DateTime?>(....)
```

Comment: But I won't be able to access the HasValue and Value methods of value because the compiler won't know it's a nullable, right?

Comment: correct; testing for NULL means it has no value. If it's not null, it has a value.

Comment: sorry, edited the code to remove that statement, made it clearer hopefully.

Comment: Correction: `Nullable<T>` is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: Andrew: sorry, you are right, nullable is a struct. the New() constraint still holds.

Comment: OK, I get it. I didn't think this would work, but I tested it out and it does. Andrew Hare's method solves my specific problem in a type-safe way, which is what I was looking for (your approach *allows* value to be nullable, whereas Andrew's requires it). But this answer helped me enhance my understanding of nullables, so +1 and thanks.

Comment: The effect of specifying the new() constraint is that the type passed in must be comparable to NULL. In this sense, it can only be a struct or class, which both implement ToString(), so for type safety I think you're covered. It suffers from the constraint that it has to have a public, parameterless constructor however. There may be another way to limit this if you study constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

Even tho it is a struct, it's been specifically disallowed in the CLR due to recursion issues that could arise.

```
Nullable<Nullable<Nullable<etc.>>>()
```

Comment: It's possible to do what he wants to do which is to pass a nullable type as a generic parameter. It's also possible to test that type for null since Nullable is no longer a value type, just test ==null

Comment: +1 for the helpful information. It is possible to pass a nullable as a generic parameter, as Oplapanax points out, but Jaimal's right, you can't define a generic method to specifically restrict to nullables, which is what I was after. Not sure why this was downvoted, because it is a helpful and technically correct answer to my question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong conceptually with a `Nullable<Nullable<T>>`.  Something like a `Dictionary<string, Nullable<int>>` might want to offer a `TryGetvalue` method whose return value contains the result along with an indication of success.  Were it not for the restrictions and quirky behaviors of `Nullable<T>`, a logical type for such a method would be a `Nullable<Nullable<int>>`.  If the return's `Hasvalue` is true, that `Value` holds the item stored in the collection with the specified key (if `Value.HasValue` is false, that would mean that's what was stored in the collection).

Comment: As it is, the fact that `Nullable<T>` uses properties rather than fields means that fetching and using a `T` from a dictionary would require that it be copied four times; an exposed-field `Nullable<T>` could in many cases reduce that to twice--not quite as good as having `TryGetValue` use an `out` parameter (which would only copy once) but still better than making at least four copies.