# Why does Nullable<T> not match as a reference type for generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, reference-type, generic-constraints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible)

I came across a very weird thing with generic type constraints. I have a class like this:

```
public SomeClass<T> where T:class
{
}
```

However, I've found I can't use nullable types as I'd expect:

```
new SomeClass<int?>();
```

I get an error that `int?` must be a reference type. Is Nullable really just a struct with syntactic sugar to make it look like a reference type?

Comment: What is the reason for that constraint? Can you provide more context? FYI Nullable is declared as: `public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead basically because using value types on this class can have unexpected behavior and big performance impacts

Comment: Then I guess the straight up answer is "yes, Nullable is a struct". I'm not quite sure what you consider to be syntactic sugar for Nullable. It would appear your only option is to roll your own.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead well you can do `int? x = null`, but you can't do that with any other value type.. so I need a restriction to something like `where T:class, T:Nullable`, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Well, as far as I remember, the CLR actually has an intimate understanding of the Nullable type. So this would explain why the C# compiler allows null to be assigned to a value type.

Comment: There is simply an implicit conversion between `null` and any `Nullable` value.  It doesn't actually store null, it just has a boolean `HasValue` and assigning null to it results in that being false and the actual `Value` property being...anything.  This means that putting a value into a nullable struct doesn't actually box it or result in it gaining reference semantics.  This does need special compiler support as there's no way to have a custom type with an implicity conversion for a struct from `null` while also not allowing any actual objects to be converted with it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is a `struct` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)) however it is the only `struct` that does not satisfy the `struct` constraint. Therefore, you cannot use a `Nullable` as a generic type parameter when either the `class` or `struct` constraints is used.

`Nullable<T>` is not just a struct with some syntatic sugar. It has special support in the CLR for some of its behavior. For example, it has special boxing behavior. Specifically, a nullable is never boxed. The underlying value is boxed. If the nullable is the null value (HasValue is false) then it is converted to a null reference. Also, conversion operators for any `Nullable<T>` to `Nullable<U>` are lifted from the conversions from `T` to `U`. These are features you wouldn't be able to implement yourself in .NET 1.0/1.1.