# How to make Generic parameter T Nullable in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm creating a generic method which should be able to return `null`.

As an example I've created this method `GetSecondSmallest(List<T>)` below. This function loops through all of the `IComparable` items and returns the second smallest item if possible. If this item does not exist it returns `null`.

```
public T? GetSecondSmallest<T>(List<T> items) where T : Nullable, IComparable
{
    if (items.Count == 0) return null;

    T smallest = items[0];
    T? secondSmallest = null;

    // Find second smallest by looping through list

    return secondSmallest;
}
```

Two example usages of this method would be:

```
GetSecondSmallest(new List<int> {4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8}) // Should return 2
GetSecondSmallest(new List<MyComparable> {new MyComparable('x')}) // Should return null
```

When you try to compile this code you'll see what the problem is here:

> **Error   CS0717** 'Nullable': static classes cannot be used as constraints

How can I make this method return either an instance of `T` or `null`?

---

**EDIT**: I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209160/4136777), but this does not answer my question, because in my situation the parameter is also generic, and should be `Nullable`. So the provided answers there aren't applicable.

Comment: @j0ey_wh The `INullable` interface is designed for use with databases. It's not an interface that `Nullable<T>` implements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wrapper class such as Tuple to wrap the resulting value.  In the example below, null is returned if there is no second smallest item, otherwise a Tuple is returned with the second smallest value.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result1 = GetSecondSmallest(new List<int>
    {
    4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8
    }); // Should return 2

    var result2 = GetSecondSmallest(new List<MyComparable>
    {
    new MyComparable('x')
    }); // Should return null

    Console.WriteLine("result1=" + result1.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine("result2 == null: " + (result2 == null));
}

public static Tuple<T> GetSecondSmallest<T>(List<T> items)where T : IComparable
{
    return items.Skip(1).Select(v => Tuple.Create(v)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't narrow `T` down as nullable *or* an object. You have to make two methods, one for `T` and one for `T?`.

```
public T? GetSecondSmallestAsNullable<T>(List<T> items) where T : struct
{
    return null;
}

public T GetSecondSmallestAsClass<T>(List<T> items) where T : class
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So basically duplicate code is the best solution here? There must be a better way

Comment: Rewrite the .NET framework to better support nullable with generics?

Comment: Another approach could be to look at using an [Option type](https://www.google.co.za/webhp?#q=option+type+in+C%23) in C# (as a wrapper generic) to indicate to the caller that there is no match on the predicate. This will then remove the struct v class dilemma with nullable types. It does however require significant refactoring of code / introduction of FP framework code.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type to Nullable, and call the method with the non nullable parameter

Simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? i = GetValueOrNull<int>(null, string.Empty);
}


public static Nullable<T> GetValueOrNull<T>(DbDataRecord reader, string columnName) where T : struct
{
    object columnValue = reader[columnName];

    if (!(columnValue is DBNull))
        return (T)columnValue;

    return null;
}
```

[Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible)

**UPD**

Like this:

```
public Nullable<T> GetSecondSmallest<T>(List<T> items) where T : IComparable
{
    if (items.Count == 0) return null;

    Nullable<T> smallest = items[0];
    Nullable<T> secondSmallest = null;

    // Find second smallest by looping through list

    return secondSmallest;
}
```

Comment: Did you try my second example usage? It doesn't work with this solution, as it now requires T to be non-nullable