# How to cast a datarow field to a generic type?

Tags: c#, database, casting, ado.net

I would like to make the following function work:

```
    T GetRowVal<T>(System.Data.DataRow dr, string fieldName)
    {
        var type=typeof(T);
        var val = dr[fieldName];
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            if (val == DBNull.Value || val == null) return null;
        return (T)val;
    }
```

Of course, not having constraints on the T type it doesn't want to return null even if it should be allowed in this case.
How can I correct this function? (Or if there is a better way to do it, please let me know).

---

For know, the approach I would use:

```
    T GetRowVal<T>(System.Data.DataRow dr, string fieldName)
    {
        var type=typeof(T);
        var val = dr[fieldName];
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            if (val == DBNull.Value || val == null) return default(T);
        return (T)val;
    }
```

---

New solution :)

```
return dr.Field<T>(fieldName);
```

Not sure it is nicer in terms of performances, but probably looks cleaner.

The implementation can be found on MS Github:

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your only option is `return default(T);`

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question with what seems to be a good response here:

[Nullable type as a generic parameter possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209160/nullable-type-as-a-generic-parameter-possible)

```
Nullable<T> GetRowVal<T>(System.Data.DataRow dr, string fieldName)
```

as the signature could work.

Comment: The issue is that it would require a cast after or a call to .Value if the type is not Nullable I guess.