# Nullable generic type that can be an int or string

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, generic-constraints

I'm trying to create an interface that will add a column to a database entity which will be used the track the user making changes.

```
public interface IAuditEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The interface will be used by different applications. So 1 application could use an integer as a key and another might use a string.

However, as it's a nullable type I get the following error: A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

How can I achieve this so I can use both value and reference types? So int or string really?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/209219/2920197

Comment: @PedroPerez You link to a thread that is way older than the new C# feature _nullable reference types_. Maybe the asker is using this new C# feature and needs and answer that considers this.

Comment: I'm using c# v8 (Core 3.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is just  to have a *generic type parameter* that can be a *reference type*, *value type*, or *nullable value type*. Just remove the `?`

```
public interface IAuditEntity<TKey>
{
   TKey UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Bob : IAuditEntity<int?>
{
   public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

If you are trying to use the *nullable reference type* feature, you will need to bump the version of your project

```
<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
<nullable>enable</nullable>
```

***Be warned** : This is not fully supported, and likely to cause issues with certain language features, and not all attributes will be useable.*

If your goal is to use *reference types* and *value types*, where the *generic parameter* is known to be a *not nullable* value type, and the *reference types* can be `null`, in *C#8* or later you can use the `notnull` *constraint* without the `?`

```
public interface IAuditEntity<TKey> where TKey : notnull
{
   TKey UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

If you would want to use *reference types* and *value types*, where the *generic parameter* is known to be *not nullable*, and the *reference types* can be `null` and also use the *nullable reference* type feature, you can use the `notnull` *constraint* and the nullable type operator `?` *C#9* or later

```
public interface IAuditEntity<TKey> where TKey : notnull
{
   TKey? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }` for TKey = int will not compile for `notnull` constraint.

Comment: @GuruStron indeed, maybe I should clarify that