# c# generic parameter non nullable

Tags: c#, nullable, non-nullable

i am trying to write a c# function which converts an instance of a nullable type to the underlying non nullable type. it should look something like this:

```
public static T TryConvertNullableToNonNullable<T,Y>(Y o) where T: notnull{
   if(o==null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));
   return (T)o;
}
```

How can I specify `Y` to be the nullable version of `T`?
I know that i could write `where Y: Nullable<T>` but this does not work since `T` is generic. is there even a way of achieving this?

thanks

Comment: `T M(T? x) where T: not null =>` if you are talking nullable reference types

Comment: While you could fix the error by adding `where T: struct`, why is this method needed in the first place?

Comment: Please specify if you're talking about nullable value types or nullable reference types. E.g. `Nullable<int>` vs `string?`

Comment: @Sweeper You'd need to make several other changes beyond just that constraint (the cast would fail to compile).   You're right that this is pointless though.  OP needs to use `.Value` on their nullable instance to get this behavior.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i am talking about Nullable value types

Comment: In addition to all of the above - method named `Try....` should not throw exceptions it should return `bool` and have `out` parameter =)

Comment: @macman sorry for the confusion. The linked answer is indeed what you're looking for.

Comment: We already have question for this exact problem (generics on nullable types) which I picked as duplicate. It is very likely that https://stackoverflow.com/a/43693232/477420 answer will resolve your problem (even if I agree that you should not be writing this particular method). If none of the answers in the suggested duplicate resolve your problem please [edit] your question clarifying what other things you tried (and obviously clarify if you need it for reference/value/both types) so this question can be considered for re-opening.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks! that did help me a lot. but i do have the question: why am i not supposed to write this method? at least to my knowlede, there are methods like ```Math.round()``` which cannot take ```double?``` as an input. how would i then proceed without such a method?

Comment: @macman because `x.Value` will behave essentially the same as code you trying to write (unless the code shown in the post is just an example of much more complicated thing you want to achieve) and that `.Value` already *documents* expectation that value is not null for anyone who is familiar with C# (unlike some custom method one would have to lookup to know what that method is doing).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that makes sense thanks for the clarification